# 14.04 crash - blank desktop icons, toolbar icons and menu icons, no desktop button on login

Tags: 14.04, themes, icons, desktop-background, gnome-classic

I work with Linux professionally, but the desktop is not something I know much about; thus the call for help from those more knowledgeable than myself.

This is a new install (8 months ago) of 14.04 on a Dell M6800 notebook.

The system crashed and dumped core showing a core listing on the screen. Upon rebooting the system I have some strange behavior that I am unable to remedy.

- All the wallpapers are missing.
- All the standard themes are present
- The System settings has all the text, but no icons at all
- The toolbar and desktop have all the icons, but they are white rectangles on the desktop and white rectangles in the toolbar with red "X"
- On the login page, there is no icon for choosing a desktop. I have gnome fallback install, from the original build.
- All icons in the Applications menu are white rectangles with a red "X"
- The Places menu icon are either missing or white rectangles with a red "X"
- Applications like firefox, thunderbird etc. work fine, either form the applications menu or from the toolbar icons.

What I have tried so far:

- moved the .config file to a backup and rebooted.
- did a "--reinstall" of the gnome, unity, gnome-fallback, lightdm, gnome-control-center, gnome-icon-theme-full, gnome-shell, ubuntu-desktop.
- Booted up from a live flash drive to make certain it was not the hardware. All icons were present and wallpapers etc. Completely normal.

Any help in correcting these issues is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This helped:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev
sudo gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache
```